# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do simple slider for my site on js, but i have problem.

I have variable "i", and i can't use it.

You can see at my code.

What is solution of this problem?

```
    var slider = [];
    var radio = [];

for (var i = 1; document.querySelector('.radio-' + i) !== null; i++) { //this variable

radio[i] = document.querySelector('.radio-' + i);
radio[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    for (var u = 1; document.querySelector('.slider' + u) !== null; u++) {
        slider[u] = document.querySelector('.slider' + u);

        if (slider[u].classList.contains('slider-show')) {
            slider[u].classList.remove('slider-show');
        }
    }
    slider[i].classList.add('slider-show'); //want to use here
});
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1):

reason of your problem is var i is setted to the last index of your loop when clicking on one of the radio button.

to keep track of value i a the time of the listener definition you have to use a closure:

```
var listener = (function (i) {

  return function(evt){

    for (var u = 1; document.querySelector('.slider' + u) !== null; u++) {
      slider[u] = document.querySelector('.slider' + u);

      if (slider[u].classList.contains('slider-show')) {
           slider[u].classList.remove('slider-show');
       }
    }
    slider[i].classList.add('slider-show');
  }
})(i);

radio[i].addEventListener('click', listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

**I.** In ES5 You need to have some connection between radio and slider, my proposition is data attribute in radio for example `data-i` and the same attribute in slider. Your problematic line will look like:

```
slider[this.dataset.i].classList.add('slider-show');
```

Both radio and sliders need have `data-i` attributes. So radio 1 has `data-i="1"`, slider 1 has `data-i="1"`.

**II.** In ES5 you can also use anonymous function with own variables scope

```
for (var i = 1; document.querySelector('.radio-' + i) !== null; i++)     { 

function(i){

    //here rest of code with addEventListener
    //i is scope variable so it will work as supposed

}(i);

}
```

**III.** In ES6 declare `i` as block variable so use `let i` in for loop instead of `var i`.